# Custom animation for UINavigationBar setItems/ pushNavigationItem / popNavigationItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm using a `UINavigationBar` in a regular `UIViewController` (not a `UINavigationController`) and updating the contents of the navigation bar using `setItems:animated`, `pushNavigationItem:animated` and `popNavigationItem:animated`, with animated set to YES.
Works fine, except that I would like the crossfade animation of the navigation bar, rather than the built-in animation which "pushes" the previous bar to left or right.

So far the only way I can see how to do this would be to manually set the title, left and right contents of the bar, using `setLeftBarButtonItems:animated`, `setRightBarButtonItems:animated` and probably a custom view for the title with `setTitleView` so that I can do the crossfade.
Anybody has a better solutions to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this and it worked:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navBar duration:2.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{

        myNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newLeftItem;
        myNavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newRightItem;
        myNavigationItem.title = @"My New Title";
    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Probably because I'm using a custom view in the title instead of just title text. I am using something similar where I update the left and right icons independently (setLeft/RightBarButtonItems:animated) and do a crossfade between two subviews in the title view.